# how to validate nested array and show message in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I've got an form data like this

[image]

What I want to achieve is that in every `question`  must be one `answer` with `correct` field. The validation is following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'questions.*.answers.*.correct' => 'required',
    ...
]);
```

But this validation requires that all `answer` fields have to be marked as correct.

So, my first question is **how to validate this array** to check if every question has one correct answer ?
And second one is, if validation fails how do I show which question doesn't have a correct answer ? Is there any wildcard like `:index` or something to use in my validation messsage?

Comment: can you add detail of dd($request->all()) after the form submission ?

Comment: @Sagar check it out.

Comment: In above case, first case is fine but second is not am I right ?

Comment: In your blade file, You have created input fields statically or dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, first question is fine. Everything is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you created form but you can make following structure that might help you.

Make your inner array 'answers' like this.

```
answers[
    'value1' => Answer 1,
    'value2' => Answer 2,
    'value3' => Answer 3,
    'value4' => Answer 4,
]
```

suppose correct answer is ans4 then, make array like this:

```
answers[
    'value1' => Answer 1,
    'value2' => Answer 2,
    'value3' => Answer 3,
    'value4' => Answer 4,
    'correct' => 'value4'
]
```

Now you can define validations like this:

```
'questions.*.answers.value1' => 'required',
'questions.*.answers.value2' => 'required',
'questions.*.answers.value3' => 'required',
'questions.*.answers.value4' => 'required',
'questions.*.answers.correct' => 'required',
```

Now you can generate custom error messages for above values.
Hope, This may help you.